# Fuentes para pseudo elementos fontawesome

Tags: php, html, css, font-awesome, icons

Tengo un problema, es mas de estetica.

Estoy haciendo un buscador. Y a dicho buscador en el placeholder le estoy poniendo un icono de `search`, estoy usando FontAwesome para esto. Segun la documentacion, lo que debo hacer es añadir un elemento y luego añadirle el pseudo elemento `class::placeholder`y aqui añadir

```
.header-search {
   margin-left: 250px;
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif !important;
}

.header-search::placeholder {
   font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
   font-weight: 300;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="header-search" placeholder="  Components...">
```

El pequeño rectangulo es el icono. Asi lo ofrece FontAwesome.

Algo asi, al placeholder le añado `font-family` de FontAwesome y el weight... el problema es que la fuente le añade tambien al texto del place holder no solo al icono. Y esa fuente no me gusta. Hay alguna forma de designar una fuente diferente para el texto?

Comment: Aqui puede haber algunas posibles soluciones https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19350291/use-font-awesome-icon-in-placeholder

Answer (score 3):

La solucion era tan sencilla como añadir la fuente principal antes de la fuente de FontAwesome.

```
.header-search::placeholder {
    font-family: 'Poppins', "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Asi el icono se añadirá, y tendra comp principal la fuente que tu pongas primero. En este caso `Poppins`...